# First part of Sass code not compiling

Tags: css, sass

I have some Sass code which is only compiling a small part of it. The rest of it will compile to nothing! I can't figure out what is going on and why it won't compile. Please see my comments to see what it does and doesn't compile:

```
//wont compile from here down to...

@mixin transition($value) {
    transition: $value;
    -webkit-transition: $value;
    -moz-transition: $value;
    -ms-transition: $value;
    -o-transition: $value;    
}

@mixin transform($value) {
    transform: $value;
    -webkit-transform: $value;
    -moz-transform: $value;
    -ms-transform: $value;
    -o-transform: $value;   
}

@mixin animation($value) {
  -webkit-animation: $value;
  -moz-animation: $value; 
  -o-animation: $value; 
-ms-animation: $value; 
  animation: $value; 
}

@mixin animation-delay($value) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: $value; 
  -moz-animation-delay: $value; 
  -o-animation-delay: $value;
    -ms-animation-delay: $value; 
  animation-delay: $value; 
}    

//Here    

//however the below code will compile

@-webkit-keyframes animateMenuItems {
  0%   { @include transform(translateX(-60%));opacity:0;}
  100% { @include transform(translateX(0%));opacity:1;}
}
```

Any idea where I've gone wrong here?

EDIT

Here is the file where it's supposed to compile:

```
.App {
    .app-content-wrap {
        background:white;
        @include transition(all 0.2s ease-out);   
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        -webkit-box-shadow: -2px -1px 14px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.18);
        -moz-box-shadow: -2px -1px 14px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.18);
        box-shadow: -2px -1px 14px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.18);        
    }
    &.sidenavActive {
        .app-content-wrap {
            transform: translate(300px,50px);
            -webkit-transform: translate(300px,50px);
            opacity:0.8;

        }
    }
}
```

I'm using webpack and the error i'm getting in the console is this:

> "no mixin named
>   transition\n\nBacktrace:\n\tsrc/css/app-containers.scss:4",

Comment: Have you checked the places you are calling these mixins?

Comment: Yes so this is where the compile error is occuring, i've updated my question with the error and the file it occurs in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mixin definitions don't compile down into the final CSS, they will only show up when you @include them in a definition. E.g: if you do

```
body{
  @include transition(foo);
 }
```

it would show up in your final CSS as:

```
body{
  transition: foo;
  -webkit-transition: foo;
  -moz-transition: foo;
  -ms-transition: foo;
  -o-transition: foo; 
}
```

**Edit after clarification of question in the comments**

It looks like it's an import issue. The imports in Sass are not links like they are in CSS, they literally pull the imported scss code in and compile it down to one file. So if you have a single file, app.scss for example, and you're putting all your mixins in a partial called _mixins.scss, and import the mixin partial first, it should be available to everything else that is being imported to app.scss.

_mixins.scss

```
@mixin my-rad-mixin(){
    some rad mixin stuff goes here
}
```

app.scss

```
@import 'mixins';

.foo{
  @include my-rad-mixin;
}
```

With this setup everything you write after the import in app.scss, including other Sass imports, should have access to everything in the _mixins partial. It will all compile out to a single app.css (assuming you don't change the name at compile time.)

If, however, you aren't using the partial system but are compiling multiple scss files to css, then you'd have to import the file with the mixin definitions everywhere you want to use the mixin.

Comment: Thanks, i've updated the question with where the compile error is occuring in another file with the actual error

Comment: Ahh, I see. That looks like you're not actually importing the file with the mixin definition to me. Are you relying on webpack to glue things together or using an import statement in in your sass?

Comment: yes so basically I had to import the mixin file in every file where I use an @include ... and then it worked. But I thought that because I included the mixins file (the first block of code where I define the mixins) at the top of my app.scss file then it would trickly down to any other includes that were included in the app.scss file after that such as in the file that contains my second bit of code but this wasn't the case. Does that sound about right to you?

Comment: The imports in Sass are not links like they are in CSS, they literally pull the imported scss code in and compile it down to one file. So if you have a single file, app.scss for example, and you're putting all your mixins in a mixin partial, _mixins.scss, and you import the mixin partial first, it should be available to everything else that is being imported to app.scss. If, however, you aren't using the partial system but are compiling multiple files to css, then you'd have to import it everywhere.

Comment: makes complete sense, if you want to edit your answer to reflect that ill mark it as correct

Comment: Just commenting to commend on the great effort behind this answer :)